# Linq to Collection Where Clause Throws Exception

Tags: c#, linq

I have a foreach loop cycling through a IEnumerable. Inside the loop a sting is built based of of parameters that change with each iteration of the loop. The string is then used to use a dynamic linq query. I would then like to apply the results to build a list of custom objects. The where clause executes for the first time through and then exits the loop. Why is it doing this? I cannot confirm if the query is executing successfully, but no exception is being raised.

```
         public List<groupingModel> getGrouping(string groupBy)
    {
        List<groupingModel> lgm = new List<groupingModel>();


        var w2 = getWVWellsList();

        var v = w2.Select(groupBy).Distinct();

        foreach(string val in v)
        {

            string whereClause = string.Format("{0} = {1}", groupBy, val);

            IEnumerable<WVWellModel> q2 = w2.Where(whereClause);
            List<WVWellModel> l = q2.ToList<WVWellModel>();

            lgm.Add(new groupingModel { Header = val, Wells = l });
        }

        return lgm;
    }
```

**EDIT - Captured Exception**

I placed the code into a try/catch and uncovered an exception that I suspect wasnt being caught due to the nature of the dynamic linq. Before I List the exception i wanted to give an example situation.

The User selects to group by state. This triggers a method that then runs the query, but it first builds a where clause based off of distinct values of the property selected. This is done by `var v = w2.Select(groupBy).Distinct();`

In this example then the first value to go through the loop is Colorado. The Where clause is then built with string `whereClause = string.Format("{0} = {1}", groupBy, val);` in this instance `groupBy` = state and `val` = colorado.. I can confirm by placing breakpoints that the string is sucessfully built and looks like `state = colorado`(ive also tried this using "==" instead of "=" as well).

When the query is executed I catch an error that states "No Property or Field "Colorado" Exists in WVWellModel" which of course is in fact true. The property I am trying to query is "State" not "Colorado". It is as if my Dynamic WhereClause is reversed or something...

I have used this blog as a reference to Dynamic Linq.

https://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library

Comment: Why does your Where function take a string as parameter?

Comment: @HungCao something like [Dynamic Linq](https://dynamiclinq.codeplex.com/documentation) I suppose

Comment: My understanding was that you can use System.Linq.Dynamic to do so. I wish to use this functionality so that my query can be dependent upon User Input.

Comment: https://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library

Comment: How does your groupby value look like?

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya it is a string value that is passed in from a combo box. The combo box was populated from the properties of the table     (converted to a list) which are also strings.

Comment: Collection "v" has enough item to loop thru?

Comment: I threw this into a try catch block and was able to produce an exception. I will edit my question to reflect what i have found.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to put the 'colorado' value inside escaped quotation marks like this:

```
string whereClause = string.Format("{0} = \"{1}\"", groupBy, val);
```

It doesn't show in the guide you linked to because the values he's searching for are integers, and - much like in SQL code - you don't need to put apostrophes (') around integers. You do when searching for text, though.